# SQL Server 2008 : select members group by with conditions

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have a table

```
CREATE TABLE #tblA (mem_id int, type varchar(20), address1 varchar(20),group_id int)

insert into #tblA (mem_id, type, address1,group_id)
values (1,'self','abc St',1),
       (2,'Child','abc St',1),
       (3,'Child','xyz st',1),
       (4,'spouse','pqr st',1),
       (5,'Child','abc St',1),
       (6,'Child','xyz st',1),

       (7,'self','mno st',2),
       (8,'Child','def St',2),
       (9,'Child','def st',2),

       (10,'self','loi st',3),
       (11,'Child','loi St',3),
       (12,'Child','ewr st',3)

       (13,'self','ooo st',NULL),
```

So, I want to select:

1. For every group, select "self".
2. Select self if it has no group.
3. If other people live at different address than self, select those
   members.
4. if multiple members live at different address, pick 1 member living
   at a different address

So expected result:

```
   (1,'self','abc St',1),
   (3,'Child','xyz st',1),
   (4,'spouse','pqr st',1),
   (7,'self','mno st',2),
   (8,'Child','def St',2),
   (10,'self','loi st',3),
   (12,'Child','ewr st',3)
   (13,'self','ooo st',NULL),
```

Thanks

My code: not working:

```
select  
   mem_id
from 
   (select 
        a.*,
        RANK() over (partition by group_id order by AddressCnt DESC) as AddressRank
    from 
        (select 
             a.*,
             (case when max(address1) over (partition by group_id) = min(address1) over (partition by group_id)
              then 1 else 0
              end) as AddressSame,
             count(*) over (partition by group_id, address1) as AddressCnt
         from #tblA a) a
   ) a
where 
   (AddressSame = 1 or type in ('Self') or
    (AddressRank > 1 OR  type in ('Self') or group_id is null
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution.

- Create a CTE identifying the "self" records.
- Create another cte identifying the "others" with a join from self to tableA
- Use row_number to find just one record for the other
- union the two cte's

```
WITH self 
     AS (SELECT * 
         FROM   tbla 
         WHERE  type = 'self'), 
     others 
     AS (SELECT a.mem_id, 
                a.type, 
                a.address1, 
                a.group_id, 
                Row_number() 
                  OVER ( 
                    partition BY a.group_id, a.address1 
                    ORDER BY a.mem_id) rn 
         FROM   self s 
                INNER JOIN tbla a 
                        ON s.group_id = a.group_id 
                           AND s.mem_id <> a.mem_id --Exclude self records
                           AND s.address1 <> a.address1 --Exclude the same address as self) 
SELECT mem_id, 
       type, 
       address1, 
       group_id 
FROM   self 
UNION 
SELECT mem_id, 
       type, 
       address1, 
       group_id 
FROM   others 
WHERE  rn = 1 
ORDER  BY mem_id
```

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e4c19/6)

Answer (score 0):

This MySQL query gives the desired output:

select * from tblA having type='self' UNION select * from tblA group by address1 having address1 not in (select address1 from tblA where type='self') ORDER by mem_id;

Comment: This question was tagged [tag:sql-server]. Your syntax wouldn't work in sql server because all columns are required to be in a aggregate function or in the group by clause.

Comment: Yeah .. you are right about that... the above query would not work on SQL server